# Add Order by option in SonataAdminBundle's Form (in Symfony 4)

Tags: sonata-admin, symfony4

I have this code in src/Admin/CambiosseiAdmin.php:

```
  $formMapper
     .......
        ->add('peticionario', ModelType::class, array(
        'class' => Bomberos::class,
        'query' => $this->modelManager->createQuery('App\Entity\Bomberos')
    ))
```

and in src/Entity/Bomberos.php I have:

```
public function __toString()
{
   return (string)$this->getNombre();
}
```

but the out nombre's list order is by id and I want change the order by nombre (name). Where can I write the 'order by' option to work it?

Answer (score 0):

In your class **src/Admin/CambiosseiAdmin.php** use the following line:

```
protected $datagridValues = ['_sort_order' => 'ASC', '_sort_by' => 'nombre.name'];
```

Given **nombre** is a field in list page.